# Share Resource from DirectX11 to Directx9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9, directx-11

let , I have two devices,first is of DirectX9 and second is of DirectX11 .
what i am doing is to calculate particles and save their data in a D3D11 texture by D3D11's Compute Shader and then i wanna use that D3D11 texture in my D3D9 device to display it.
i am using following code..

In D3D11 device..(m_pBuffer is ID3D11Buffer )

```
 IDXGIResource* pTempResource(NULL);
 hr = m_pBuffer->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&pTempResource );
 hr = pTempResource->GetSharedHandle(&SharedHandle); //successful
```

Then in D3D9 device...

```
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateTexture(width, height, 1, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET,D3DFMT_A32B32G32R32F,D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,&pSharedTexture9,&SharedHandle);
```

The Error i am having is "Direct3D9: (ERROR) :Opened and created resources don't match, unable to open the shared resource."

EDITED: Ok , it worked when i create texture  using D3DFMT_A16B16G16R16F in dx9 and DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT in dX11. but using D3DFMT_A32B32G32R32F and DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT , it gives the above error.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting that error because those texture formats are not allowed.

> Textures being shared from D3D9 to D3D11 have the following restrictions:
>
> - Textures must be 2D
> - Only 1 mip level is allowed
> - Texture must have default usage
> - Texture must be write only
> - MSAA textures are not allowed
> - Bind flags must have SHADER_RESOURCE and RENDER_TARGET set
> - Only R10G10B10A2_UNORM, R16G16B16A16_FLOAT and R8G8B8A8_UNORM formats are allowed

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So for sharing textures, you are limited to the three formats stated above. Additionally, if you intend to use the texture as a backbuffer in Direct3D9, you are further limited to R8G8B8A8_UNORM and R10G10B10A2_UNORM. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#BackBuffer_or_Display_Formats

Comment: SORRY BUT even R16G16B16A16_FLOAT  is not working,i was wrong.I think its a non-working feature as most of the posts on other forums says it. anyone got it working ?

Comment: The problem is that while it is a valid format for sharing, you cannot have a 64 bit backbuffer in Direct3D9.